# selecting value in one row of DataFrame based on value in other

Tags: python, pandas

i have the following example DataFrame

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[5,0,-3],['nyc','sf','chi']]), columns=['col1','col2','col3'], index=['value','location'])
```

for this example, i want to retrieve the number in the 'value' row where the 'location' = 'nyc', so in this case, i want to retrieve the number 5. i am trying to use the .loc with a boolean but can't quite get it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need two `.loc`

```
df2.loc['value',df2.loc['location']=='nyc']
Out[269]: 
col1    5
Name: value, dtype: object
```

If only need value output

```
df2.loc['value',df2.loc['location']=='nyc'].iloc[0]
Out[270]: '5'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the value in the `value` row, but I am indexing it using `iloc` instead of `loc`:

```
df2.iloc[0, np.where(df2.loc['location', ] == 'nyc')[0]].values
```

OUTPUT:

```
array(['5'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: how do you just get "5"?

Comment: @laszlopanaflex Updated